# Migrating from Hibernate 4.X to 6.X Projections deprecated

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I am migrating from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 6 and I am not sure if the code I have written is the equivalent code from the Old Code Snippet for Projections.

Old Code Snippet

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ABCD.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("123", "456");
Long ll = ((Long) criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
```

New Code Snippet

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<ABCD> root = criteriaQuery.from(ABCD.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("123"), "456"));
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));
Long ll = getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
```

Here the Line `criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())` has been replaced by `criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));` Is it logically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to write `count(*)` in the criteria API, but Christian Beikov suggests using `count(1)`, that is:

```
criteriaBuilder.count(criteriaBuilder.literal(1))
```

which is a bit more robust than your suggestion.